# docker build problem with npm install Error: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org Socket timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm

docker build problem with npm install and it's only inside docker I've tested. it's working on my os perfectly

Error

```
Step 6/8 : RUN npm cache clear --force &&  npm install --legacy-peer-deps
 ---> Running in 361c2a07ac22
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.4.1 -> 8.5.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.5.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.5.0` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/styled-jsx: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-17T07_12_06_500Z-debug-0.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm cache clear --force &&  npm install --legacy-peer-deps' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

docker file

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PORT 3000

COPY ./package.json /app/
COPY ./.npmrc ~

RUN npm cache clear --force &&  npm install --legacy-peer-deps

COPY . /app/

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

as u can see I have added .npmrc file because I have read it somewhere but it didn't work or add `npm cache clear --force` so what should I do?

Comment: Maybe separate two line like `RUN npm cache clear --force` and `RUN  npm install --legacy-peer-deps` to see the logs separatly?

Comment: We missed the files you are copying to the docker image to run some tests

Answer (score -1):

What version of Node your app is using? And what version of node you have installed on your OS?

You can check it using:

```
node -v
```

This image you used `node:alpine` is the newest version of the node, currently it's 17. So maybe you should use older one (the one you actualy have in your app).
You can find correct image on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)